# Sails.js How to load session and create, check, destroy?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-redis

In config session.js i have enabled redis
before that i have installed these two things...

npm install connect-redis

npm install express

```
           adapter: 'redis',
          //
          // on localhost is expected.
          // Read more about options at: https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis
          //
           host: 'localhost',
           port: 6379,
           ttl: 3600,
           db: 0,
           pass: '',
           prefix: 'sess:'
```

In controller 2

//assign the value in session and redirect to controller1
req.session.error = "category Not found";

//error
TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined

```
            module.exports = {

              load_word: function(req, res){ 
                 var async = require('async');
                 var express = require('express');
                 var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

                 async.waterfall([
                        function(callback){
                            Category.findOne().where({keyword:req.param('keyword')}).done(function(err,category){
                                if(category==undefined){ 
                                    req.session.error = "category Not found";
                                    res.redirect('home');
                                }else{
                                    category_id = category.id;
                                }
                                /*Word.findOne().where({id:category_id}).done(function(err,word){ 

                                });*/
                            });
                        },
```

Controller 1

console.log(req.session.error);

```
           module.exports = {

          /**
           * Action blueprints:
           *    `/home/index`
           *    `/home`
           */
           index: function (req, res) {
            var async = require('async');
            var express = require('express');
            var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
            var data = new Object();

                console.log(req.session.error);
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

To check if category is undefined or not use
`if(typeof(category)!='undefined){}`